Why can't I store a character array in a union?
Below is some code I wrote while practicing creating a union type:
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union{
    int num;
    char str[6];
}Data;

int main()
{
    Data data;
    data.num = 6;
    // printf("%s\n", data.str);
    printf("%d\n", data.num);
    data.str = "red";
    printf("%d\n", data.num);
    printf("%s", data.str);
    return 0;
}

I am getting a squiggle on the line of code where I am storing the string "red" in the str property of the union Data. The error message I get:
expression must be a modifiable lvalue C/C++(137)

If iI wrote the code as below however:
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union{
    int num;
    char* str;
}Data;

int main()
{
    Data data;
    data.num = 6;
    // printf("%s\n", data.str);
    printf("%d\n", data.num);
    data.str = "red";
    printf("%d\n", data.num);
    printf("%s", data.str);
    return 0;
}

the code compiles and the code runs. Why is that?

The problem is not the union but the fact that you can't assign to arrays in runtime. Use strcpy in this case.
